# Kivy label text won't update

Tags: python, kivy

I'm not new to python but I am new-ish to Kivy.
I don't know what parts of my code you need to answer this but here is all my code:

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

import os

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MainPage(BoxLayout): 
    sound = None
    playing = False
    song_text = StringProperty("None")
    
    volume_text = StringProperty("50")
    volume_num = NumericProperty(50)
    volume = 50 /100
    
    def on_button_1_click(self):
        if self.playing:
            self.sound.stop()
            self.sound = SoundLoader.load('music/Gold.mp3')
            self.song_text = "Gold"
            print("Gold")
            self.sound.play()
            self.sound.volume = self.volume
        else:
            self.sound = SoundLoader.load('music/Gold.mp3')
            self.song_text = "Gold"
            print("Gold")
    
    def on_button_2_click(self):
        if self.playing:
            self.sound.stop()
            self.sound = SoundLoader.load('music/Run For Your Life.mp3')
            self.song_text = "Run For Your Life"
            print("Run For Your Life")
            self.sound.play()
            self.sound.volume = self.volume
        else:
            self.sound = SoundLoader.load('music/Run For Your Life.mp3')
            self.song_text = "Run For Your Life"
            print("Run For Your Life")
    
    def on_button_3_click(self):
        if self.playing:
            self.sound.stop()
            self.sound = SoundLoader.load('music/Spirits Say.mp3')
            self.song_text = "Spirits Say"
            print("Spirits Say")
            self.sound.play()
            self.sound.volume = self.volume
        else:
            self.sound = SoundLoader.load('music/Spirits Say.mp3')
            self.song_text = "Spirits Say"
            print("Spirits Say")
    
    def on_play_button_click(self):
        if self.sound is not None:
            if not self.playing:
                #print("Sound found at %s" % self.sound.source)
                print("Sound start")
                self.sound.play()
                self.playing = True
                self.sound.volume = self.volume
            else:
                print("Song is playing")
        else:
            print("Choose a song")
    
    def on_stop_button_click(self):
        if self.sound is not None: 
            if self.playing:
                print("Sound stopped")
                self.sound.stop()
                self.playing = False
            else:
                print("Start playing a song")
        else:
            print("Choose a song")
    
    def volume_slider_value(self, widget):
        self.volume_text = str(int(widget.value))
        self.volume = round(widget.value/100,2)
        if self.playing:
            self.sound.volume = self.volume

class SongList(StackLayout):
    SONG_LIST = []
    for _,i in enumerate(os.listdir("music")):
        SONG_LIST.append(i.replace(".mp3","").capitalize())
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
        for __,i in enumerate(self.SONG_LIST):
            size = dp(125)
            b = Button(text=str(i), size_hint=(None, None), size=(size, size))
            b.bind(on_press=self.Button_Click)
            self.add_widget(b)
    
    def Button_Click(self, widget):
        print("song: " + widget.text)
        if MainPage.playing:
            MainPage.sound.stop()
            path = os.path.join("music",(widget.text+".mp3"))
            MainPage.sound = SoundLoader.load(path)
            MainPage.song_text = widget.text
            MainPage.sound.play()
            MainPage.sound.volume = MainPage.volume
        else:
            path = os.path.join("music",(widget.text+".mp3"))
            MainPage.sound = SoundLoader.load(path)
            MainPage.song_text = widget.text
            print(widget.text)

class Playlists(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(0,10):
            size = dp(100)
            b = Button(text=str(i+1), size_hint=(None, None), size=(size, size))
            b.bind(on_press=self.playlist_button_pressed)
            self.add_widget(b)
    
    def playlist_button_pressed(self, widget):
        print(widget.text)
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.root.transition.direction = 'down'
        app.root.current = 'playlist'

class PlaylistScreen(Screen):
    pass

class PlaylistSongs(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TunesApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='main'))
        sm.add_widget(PlaylistScreen(name='playlist'))
        
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TunesApp().run()
```

**tunes.kv**

```
MainScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    id: mainscreen
    Pages:

<Pages@PageLayout>:
    MainPage:
    SongListScroll:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Label:
            text: "PLAYLISTS"
            font_size: "50dp"
            size_hint: 1, .25
        Playlists:

<MainPage>:
    id: mainpage
    orientation: "vertical"
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        id: favourites
        Button:
            text: "Gold"
            on_press: root.on_button_1_click()
            size_hint: .25, 1
        Button:
            text: "Run For Your Life"
            on_press: root.on_button_2_click()
            size_hint: .25, 1
        Button:
            text: "Spirits Say"
            on_press: root.on_button_3_click()
            size_hint: .25, 1
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: song_label
            text: "Playing: " + root.song_text
        Slider:
            id: volume_sider
            min: 0
            max: 100
            value: 50
            step: 1
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint: .125, 1
            on_value: root.volume_slider_value(self)
            curser_size: "100dp", "100dp"
            color: .5, 0, 1, 1
        Label:
            text: root.volume_text
            size_hint: .125, 1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        id: controls
        Button:
            text: "Play"
            on_press: root.on_play_button_click()
        Button:
            text: "Stop"
            on_press: root.on_stop_button_click()

<SongListScroll@ScrollView>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Label:
            text: "SONGS"
            font_size: "50dp"
            size_hint: 1, .25
        SongList:
            #size_hint: 1, None
            #height: self.minimum_height

<SongList>:
    orientation: "lr-tb"

<Playlists>:
    Button:
        text: "1"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: "100dp", "100dp"
        on_press:
            app.root.transition.direction = 'down'
            app.root.current = 'playlist'

<PlaylistScreen>:
    PlaylistSongs:

<PlaylistSongs>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    Button:
        text: "Back"
        on_press:
            app.root.transition.direction = 'up'
            app.root.current = 'main'
```

The label with `id: song_label` won't update the text from `Button_Click` from `SongList`.
I've been searching the internet for answers for this and can't find anything. Please help.
Also any improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot refer to a `Property` as though it were a class variable. You must reference it through the instance. So, when you are trying to set `song_text` in `MainPage`, you must get a reference to the instance of `MainPage` in your GUI. In order to help with that, you can add some `ids` in your `kv`:

```
<MainScreen>:
    id: mainscreen
    Pages:
        id: pages

<Pages@PageLayout>:
    MainPage:
        id: mainpage
    SongListScroll:
    BoxLayout:
    .
    .
    .
```

Then, you can use these new `ids` to access the `MainPage` instance in your `py` code:

```
App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('main').ids.pages.ids.mainpage.song_text = widget.text
```